# Interface CallBack error .. looping until it crashes - KOTLIN

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, interface, fragment

I have two interfaces ...

```
interface Calculator { fun getResult(input: String?): Result? }
```

```
interface Result { val asString: String }
```

i am able to initialize Calculator interface, but when i am trying to Callback, i get an error message ...for looping Stackoverflow error message..
Any idea why? how can i solve this problem?
I know the problem is in this line

***override fun getResult(input:String?):Result=getResult(textInputEditText.text.toString()) ***-

but i dont know how to fix it, any help is really welcome! thanks in advance
for your time and help!!

```
class ComputeFragment @ContentView constructor() : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_task) {

    private var taskBinding: FragmentTaskBinding? = null
    private val calculator: Calculator? = null

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if (context is Calculator) {
            calculator = context
        } else {
            throw RuntimeException(context.toString() + " must implement 
             Calculator interface")
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, 
      savedInstanceState:Bundle?): View {
        val binding = FragmentTaskBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        taskBinding = binding
        return binding.root


    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        taskBinding
                ?.buttonFirst
                ?.setOnClickListener {
                    NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@ComputeFragment).navigate(R.id.action_FirstFragment_to_SecondFragment)
                }


        
        taskBinding
                ?.buttonCompute
                ?.setOnClickListener { v: View ->
                    if (calculator == null) {
                        Snackbar.make(v, R.string.please_implement, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        return@setOnClickListener

                    }else {
                        val result  = calculator.getResult(taskBinding?.textInputEditText?.text.toString())
                        taskBinding?.result?.text = result?.asString

               }}}}
```

````
class TaskActivity : appCompatActivity() , Calculator {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar}
    }
    override fun getResult(input: String?): Result? = 
          getResult(textInputEditText.text.toString())
   }}```
````

Comment: with the question you've posted, i don't understand 1) why you'd need an interface for this because 2) you've posted no relevant details to how/where you'll be using this. the signatures of 2 interfaces _really_ doesn't tell me anything

Comment: shall i post the entire code again? @a_local_nobody?

Comment: `shall i post the entire code again` you _always_ have to post all relevant code. stack overflow serves as a great place to help you debug, but the point of SO is to create something for others in future. answer to questions aren't here _just_ to help you, it's for everyone in future as well

Comment: i _really_ don't understand your problem, interfaces do more than just allow you to "communicate", so just implement the interfaces ?